# Symfony "deduplication" log hanlder not found

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8, monolog, symfony3.x

I am using sample config from symfony documentation page to send logs via email https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/logging/monolog_email.html

```
monolog:
handlers:
    main:
        type:         fingers_crossed
        # 500 errors are logged at the critical level
        action_level: critical
        # to also log 400 level errors (but not 404's):
        # action_level: error
        # excluded_404s:
        #     - ^/
        handler:      deduplicated
    deduplicated:
        type:    deduplication
        handler: swift
    swift:
        type:       swift_mailer
        from_email: 'error@example.com'
        to_email:   'error@example.com'
        subject:    'An Error Occurred! %%message%%'
        level:      debug
        formatter:  monolog.formatter.html
        content_type: text/html
```

I am getting an error
**Invalid handler type "deduplication" given for handler "deduplicated"**

I am not sure what's wrong as i am doing exactly same as in documentation, or i have to configure something.

Comment: Which monolog version did you've installed?

Comment: this one "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.8.1",

Comment: This feature was added in [1.19](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1190-2016-04-12) version of `monolog/monolog`. You are using 1.8 see package [dependencies](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/monolog-bundle#2.8.1) of `symfony/monolog-bundle`

Answer (score 0):

Related to the Github-Repository there is indeed no option "deduplication" for the type.

https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/2.8.1/DependencyInjection/MonologExtension.php

Just upgrade your version via composer.

Comment: Ok How to use Mandrill handler?